# Three20 Rejection from Apple

Tags: app-store, three20, appstore-approval

I'm rejected from Apple Store 3 times, because I have the three20 Library.
My project is in distribution configration, and DEBUG is Disabled.
I got this message from Apple:

```
Private Symbol References
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._locationInWindow
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._phase
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._previousLocationInWindow
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._tapCount
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._timestamp
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._touchFlags
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._view
OBJC_IVAR_$_UITouch._window
```

I'm using the last three20 lib from Github (v1.0a2), for photo galerie
I deleted also the #if debug code in the UITouche, but still rejected from Apple.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: I installed Three20 with this method : http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project

Comment: I use Xcode Version 3.2.4, My project have Base SDK : 4.1 and target SDK 3.0

Comment: Did you clean your build and three20's build? This is caused by UIViewAdditions.m when in debug mode. Are you sure all targets, including three20's ones are compiled as `Release`?

Comment: I changed all Three20 project by Click Right on project -> Get Info, and clonned Release configuration to create Distribution configuration, and Clean all target, and build, maybe i miss something ? Have I delete the three20 Build directory, and return to release configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try removing the static library or the dependencies on the part of the Three20 that you are not using in your project.

Comment: I removed dependencies. and reinstalled the Three20 like this : python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/myProject.xcodeproj -c Distribution  Three20. It's OK now